# OptaPlanner: Score Corruption solving certain datasets?

Tags: java, optaplanner

When I'm trying to solve a certain dataset, I get this error (with environmental mode set to full_assert)

```
14:14:40.603 [main] INFO o.o.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver - Solving started: time spent (39), best score (0hard/0medium/-18soft), environment mode (FULL_ASSERT), random (JDK with seed 0).
14:14:41.608 [main] DEBUG o.o.c.i.l.DefaultLocalSearchPhase -     LS step (0), time spent (1045), score (0hard/0medium/-17soft), new best score (0hard/0medium/-17soft), accepted/selected move count (466/466), picked move (Assignment ID: 14 --- [Employee ID: N/A | Shift ID: 737] {null -> 4 Chef(admin) Bossen}).
14:14:41.667 [main] ERROR org.optaplanner - Caught exception!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Score corruption: the workingScore (0hard/0medium/-16soft) is not the uncorruptedScore (0hard/-4medium/-16soft) after completedAction (Assignment ID: 17 --- [Employee ID: 4 | Shift ID: 746] {4 Chef(admin) Bossen -> 4 Chef(admin) Bossen}):
  The corrupted scoreDirector has no ConstraintMatch(s) which are in excess.
  The corrupted scoreDirector has 1 ConstraintMatch(s) which are missing:
    org.avalin.optaplannerhellotest.solver/MaximumHoursPerWeekExceeded/[4 Chef(admin) Bossen, Week: 12, org.avalin.optaplanner.service.Service@726a17c4]=0hard/-4medium/0soft
  Check your score constraints.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractScoreDirector.java:496)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.scope.DefaultSolverScope.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(DefaultSolverScope.java:132)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.phase.scope.AbstractPhaseScope.assertWorkingScoreFromScratch(AbstractPhaseScope.java:167)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.processMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:163)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.doMove(LocalSearchDecider.java:148)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(LocalSearchDecider.java:120)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:70)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:87)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:167)
    at org.avalin.optaplanner.main.EmployeeRoster.main(EmployeeRoster.java:77)
```

This is my constraint:

```
rule "MaximumHoursPerWeekExceeded"
    when
         $employee : Employee()
         $week : Week()

         $service : Service
         (
             getWeeklyDurationForEmployee($employee, $week) > $employee.getDuration($employee.getMaxHoursPerWeek)
         )
         eval(isDroolActivated("MaximumHoursPerWeekExceeded", $service))
    then
        setDroolRating(scoreHolder, kcontext, $service.getDroolStrength(drools),  $service.getDroolWeight(drools) + (int) ($service.getWeeklyDurationForEmployee($employee, $week)/3600 -  $employee.getDuration($employee.getMaxHoursPerWeek())/3600)-1);
end
```

For some reason this don't happen in other data sets I've tested which had different constraints and constraint settings, (soft/medium/hard and different weights) but of course still kept the "MaximumHoursPerWeek" constraint.

I learned that if I replace this line:

```
getWeeklyDurationForEmployee($employee, $week)
```

with a random number, it will run without saying there's a score corruption.

This method is looping through assignments that have been currently dealt to the given employee. 
"Assignment" is my planning entity. Could this be a problem? Is this where shadow variables are handy? I tried to make my list of assignments a "    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(...)" but it didn't change anything

Comment: Side note: for `isDroolActivated`, I would use the Parametrization pattern like in the exam example

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that any of those methods called on the RHS, might rely on planning variable in a planning entity that is part of the rule pattern here, so drools doesn't re-evaluate the rule when it gets an event that that planning entity's planning variable is modified.

Comment: It happens still even if I change the RHS to simply : "setDroolRating(scoreHolder, kcontext, $service.getDroolStrength(drools), -1);"